# How to fix "Android license status unknown" in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-manager

my flutter doctor -v result:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.472], locale fa-IR)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at C:\Android\flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (6 weeks ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at c:\Android\android-sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 27.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Android\android-sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    X Android license status unknown.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 29.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • HUAWEI CUN U29 • CCMBBCB6C0153603 • android-arm • Android 5.1 (API 22)
```

and when run:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

get me this result:

```
A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
c:\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update
```

and when update sdkmanager show this error to me:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FN_AAPT2
        at com.android.sdklib.BuildToolInfo.<init>(BuildToolInfo.java:362)
```

How can i solve this challenge?

Comment: This issue is being discussed here - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16025

Comment: i need help how to update sdk manager

Answer (score -11, accepted):

Uninstall Android Studio or the Android SDK. Reinstall it.

Comment: you just need to Install Android SDK Command-line Tools from Adnroid SDK. No need to uninstall the whole studio and SDK

Answer (score 23):

[image]

I solved this problem by installing the command line tool.

[image]

And then rerun

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

I have followed these steps. It worked for me.

1. went to Environment variables and added `ANDROID_HOME` with a variable value of:
   `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`
2. then my `JAVA_HOME` with this variable value:
   `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`
3. then my Path with this variable value:
   `C:\Users\%username%\flutter\bin`
4. then I ran the following command

   ```
   flutter doctor
   ```
5. Got the output of Doctor summary (to see all details, run `flutter doctor -v`):

   ```
   [√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.309], 
   locale en-US)
   [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
   ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor -- 
   android-licenses
   [√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
   [√] Connected devices (1 available)

   ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
   ```
6. Then I ran

   ```
   flutter doctor --android-licenses
   ```

   and accepted all Terms & Conditions with (y)

Answer (score 4):

1. Install `Android SDK Command-line Tools` on android studio using the SDK manager
2. Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Answer (score 2):

Now this problem with the license has got to do with the java development kit(JDK) version.
For some reasons if you are not using JDK 8 or below, you will unfortunately get license issues.So basically uninstall current version and install JDK 8 or below. Check link below and follow the conversation carefully.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16025

Comment: One Solution is to install JDK 8 or lower and then set JAVA_HOME in your User- and System Environment Variables correctly.

Comment: On Mac, I had both JDK 8 and 14 installed. I forgot to switch environment to use 8 and got licensing message. Switched backed to 8 and it went away.

Answer (score 1):

I solved pb (jdk11 on Win10 at beginning) following Nitesh steps (thanks) but with some change due to win10 strange behavior ( i know...).
To objectify, create two environment'variables with win10 wizards :
I strike :
`TEST1  C:\Users\%username%\XXX 
 TEST2  %USERPROFILE%\YYY`
Appear correct in wizard:
`TEST1 C:\Users\pirla\XXX
 TEST2 C:\Users\pirla\YYY`
But in a dos command window, this comes to SYSTEM in first case despite correct username :
`C:\Users\pirla>echo %username%
 pirla
C:\Users\pirla>set TEST
TEST1=C:\Users\SYSTEM\XXX
TEST2=C:\Users\pirla\YYYY`

So replace
`C:\Users\%username%\`
by
`%USERPROFILE%\`
and averything is ok. 
*( by the way, if you have also an JRE_HOME , change it too )*

HTH

Answer (score 1):

There is an SDK Manager Icon in the top right of Android Studio between the AVD manager icon and the magnifying glass.  Click it.
You get a modal that shows you are in System Settings -> Android SDK n the left menu.  In the middle area there is an SDK Tools tab so click it.
Check off the box that says "Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)" and click Apply.  It will install it (about 105M).  Now run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and say yes to everything.  The error should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Use flutter_console instead of CMD

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Comment: Where is this console fir mac? I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. open Android Studio's SDK Manager
2. go to the Android SDK tab
3. under SDK Tools, uncheck Hide Obsolete Packages
4. install Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:** None of the above works when setting up a Windows 10 Flutter 1.17.1 environment for mobile development. The quickest and easiest solve is to download android-studio-ide-193.6514223-windows (Android 4.0) from https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.

1. Download Android 4.0
2. Install Command
3. Line Tools in SDK Settings
4. Reboot Open Command Prompt

   flutter doctor -v

Answer (score 0):

You must install Android SDK Command-line Tool(Latest).
Go to **SDK Manager in android studio**, in tab **SDK Tools**, check in **Android SDK Command-line Tool(Latest)** and then click "apply".

Answer (score 0):

For those who tried all the answers above and nothing worked, Updating the jdk path in jdk location in android studio (+JAVA_HOME path )  worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you have tried everything, try uninstalling the following things

- flutter: extension from vscode, plugin from android studio and the sdk(delete it from file explorer and also remove it from path)
- in android studio go to the sdk tools and uninstall the commandline tools and also the platform tools including the obsolete.

once your done with that download the latest version of flutter sdk and set it to path.
install the flutter plugin and also commandline and platform tools.
then go to vscode and install the flutter extension.
set every thing up again and run flutter doctor

tldr: uninstall flutter,the plugins from android studio, extension from vscode and reinstall it.

Answer (score -1):

On Windows:
open cmd and run:

```
android update sdk
```

After that run `flutter doctor` again

Answer (score -2):

in terminal :

1. `flutter update`
2. `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
3. accept all terms by `y`